# Regex extracting sets of numbers from string when prefix occurs, while not matching said prefix

Tags: regex, go

As stated in the title, given a situation where I have a string like so:

```
"somestring~200~122"
```

I am wanting to regex to match the numbers when the prefix "~" occurs. So I can ultimately end up with [200, 122].

Matching the prefix is necessary as I need to protect against a case where a string like the one below should not be matched

```
"somestring~abc200~def122"
```

For additional context: As stated in the title, I am using go so I am planning on using doing something like the following in order to obtain the numbers within the string:

```
pattern := regexp.MustCompile("regex i need help with")
numbers := pattern.FindAllString(host, -1)
```

Comment: `(?<=~)\d+` Unsupported Perl syntax `(?<`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`FindAllStringSubmatch`](https://godoc.org/regexp#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch) to extract the group containing just the digits. Below is an example that finds all instances of `~` followed by numbers. It additionally converts all the matches to ints 
and inserts them into a slice:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    host := "somestring~200~122"
    pattern := regexp.MustCompile(`~(\d+)`)
    numberStrings := pattern.FindAllStringSubmatch(host, -1)
    numbers := make([]int, len(numberStrings))
    for i, numberString := range numberStrings {
        number, err := strconv.Atoi(numberString[1])
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        numbers[i] = number
    }
    fmt.Println(numbers)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/09YyewtRXz